# mathematical process in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10000,5))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C','D','Output'])

df.head()
```

I will create dataframe

```
  if a** 4+b** 3+c**2+d %2 == 0:
    return 0:  (output=0)
  else:
    return 1:   (output=1)
```

how can ı write output values

Comment: To help get you started, look at the output of df.A**4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you intend for the `%` operation to apply to `(a**4 + b**3 + c**2 + d)`, you can update the `Output` column of the dataframe like this:

```py
df['Output'] = (((df.A**4 + df.B**3 + df.C**2 + df.D) %2) != 0).astype(int)
```

Output of `df.head()`:

```
   A  B  C  D  Output
0  9  8  4  9       0
1  6  5  9  5       1
2  3  6  1  3       1
3  8  3  3  0       0
4  8  3  5  7       1
```